# AngularJS / Ionic does not update all the UI?

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, safari

I have an AngularJS / Ionic App (I don't know whether the issue is related to Ionic or Angujar). Recently the UI has begun to behave differently in Safari (both on IOS and on a MacBook). Check out the pictures:

[image]

When I push the plus button, 250 is added to the 3000. In the next picture I've pushed to button a couple of times and this happens:

[image]

It should say 3750. It is like the bottom part of the number has been updated, but not the top part?